# android overlay picture not reaching top of screen

Tags: java, android, overlay, android-windowmanager

I am trying to fit this overlay image to the very top of the screen:

[image]

This is my code for the overlay:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
    wm.addView(overlayedButton, params);
```

Why is the picture not meeting the top of the screen? Thanks for any pointers!

Here is the image of the sun:

[image]

Comment: Could you give more context? Like the picture and what you are trying to get?

Comment: I should have explained that this is a half sun and I am trying to get the horizontal top of the png aligned with the top of the screen.

Comment: @creativecreatormaybenot I added a screenshot of what I'm looking for.

Comment: I am talking about the image file of the sun ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was using an ImageButton rather than an ImageView.